# Rails: Get phone_number of persons in city

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

i need to get all the phone numbers of people in one city, i have my db like this:

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :persons
end
...
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :city
    has_many :phones
end
...
class Phone < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :person
end
...
```

so i neet to get all the phones in one city with something like this:

```
City.find(1).persons.phones
```

Any help?

Currently i use this:

```
ids=City.find(1).persons.ids
phones=Phones.where(id: ids)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the nested has_many associations and then apply where clause like this:

```
Phone.joins(person: :city).where(cities: {id: 1})
```

Comment: see adove what i use.

Comment: this work! Just in "where(**city**: {id: 1})" y need to use where(**cities**: {id: 1})